# Help in Finding a specific Quantum Mechanics Book with Minimal Formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, specific-reference

I'm reaching out to this wonderful community in the hopes that someone can assist me in identifying a particular book on the topic of quantum mechanics that I read nearly 25 years ago. Unfortunately, I can't recall the book's title or the author's name, but I have some distinct details that might help pinpoint it.

The book I'm looking for has a unique approach to explaining quantum mechanics. It focused primarily on providing detailed explanations rather than bombarding the reader with complex mathematical formulas. The author repeatedly reassured the reader not to worry about the math, emphasizing that the book was more about understanding the concepts.

I remember the book being relatively small, approximately A5 in size, and containing around 150 to 175 pages. It was a concise and approachable introduction to the topic, making it an excellent resource for those looking to grasp the fundamentals of quantum mechanics without getting bogged down in math.

If this description sounds familiar to anyone or if you have any leads on a book that matches these criteria, please let me know. I'd greatly appreciate your help in finding this book, as it left a lasting impression on me, and I'd love to revisit it.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of books matching (or at least trying to match) that description

Comment: Maybe "Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum" by Leonard Susskind?

Comment: Shot in the dark:  [*Primer of Quantum Mechanics*](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-Quantum-Mechanics-Dover-Physics/dp/0486428788) by Marvin Chester?  The Dover reprint is from 2003 but the original was published in 1992.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how asking for a specific book is "opinion based" that warranted the close vote?

Comment: @Ubi Can you provide other details? For instance, color of the book? Was it in English? Can you recall if the author's name was German, Russian, etc?

Comment: @Alex 25 years ago was the late 1990s. Susskind's works were written 2005 and later (with the QM one being written like 10 years ago). Unless OP has a time machine, it'd be unlikely for such a recent book to be the answer.

Comment: @Ubi.B is probably looking for [QED: A Strange Theory of Light and Matter](https://www.google.de/books/edition/QED/Uv-uxB0sRKEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) by Feynman. Fits the bill in terms of the size, page count and the assurances with regards to the mathematics. Was published in '85 and quite popular in the late 90's and even today.